# Salesforce1 mobile app not opening external web page

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, android

On my VisualForce page, I have a link that opens an external page(HTTPS) in a new window. When clicking the link **Salesforce1 mobile app** on **Android**, I'm getting the following error:

> You can't view this page, either because you don't have permission or
>   because the page isn't supported on mobile devices.

Weird thing is that the page opens in Web, Salesforce1 mobile browser in my case Chrome and on Salesforce1 iOs app. No clue in the debug logs as well.

Any idea how to go about to debug this? Any specific considerations when opening external links from Salesforce1 app on Android?

Thanks

Comment: Issue added to list of known issues in the following link: [Known Issues](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000wlSH)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding to your link target="_blank" . I was launching a mobile app from Salesforce1 and this worked for me. Before this build my url worked just fine.