# Salesforce mobile app, android device an external URL does not open

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, hyperlink, salesforce-mobile-app

I created a new quick action and on click of the button, it makes a call to apex controller and returns a link and that link must must be opened and should work on desktop and mobile.

It works on Desktop and Apple Phone but for some reason when quick action button is pressed, it flickers and stays on the same screen on android device Salesforce mobile app.

I tried the solution in the link below but did not help either.

[Salesforce1 mobile app not opening external web page](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/80774/salesforce1-mobile-app-not-opening-external-web-page)

Component

```
<aura:component controller="GetURLController" implements="force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickAction,lightning:isUrlAddressable"  access="global">   
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
</aura:component>
```

Controller

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {   
        var recordId = component.get('v.recordId');
        var action = component.get('c.getURL');
        action.setParams({opportunityId: recordId});
        action.setCallback(this, function(a){
            var state = a.getState(); // get the response state
            var url = a.getReturnValue();
            if(state == 'SUCCESS') {
                var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
                urlEvent.setParams({
                    "url": url
                });
                urlEvent.fire();
                //window.open(url,"_blank");
            }else if(state == 'ERROR'){
                helper.showError(message);
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
        $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire();
    }
})
```